# Is $\{\{a\}\}$ always a basis for the system of neighborhoods at $a$? If yes, what is the significance of the basis?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is $\{\{a\}\}$ always a basis for the system of neighborhoods at $a$? If yes, what is the significance of the basis?

I am reading the definition in Mendelson's "Introduction to Topology" book at DEFINITION 4.9:

"Let $a$ be a point in a metric space $X$. A collection $\mathscr{B}_a$ of neighborhoods of $a$ is called a basis for the neighborhood system at $a$ if every neighborhood $N$ of $a$ contains some element $B$ of $\mathscr{B}_a$."

Comment: A basis is a set of open sets, so $\{\{a\}\}$ is a basis only if $\{a\}$ is open, which is true only if $a$ is a discrete point in your topological space.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't know what open sets are. I think I understand your point though. If $a$ is not a discrete point, then $\{a\}$ cannot be a neighborhood of $a$ to begin with, and $\{\{a\}\}$ isn't even a collection of neighborhoods.